# Where should I create a local db, and connect-disconnect from a database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, database-connection

in a college project I have a Java application,

the main method do some stuff, then call a method that every 10 seconds:
-connects to a local database, (localhost, username and password are known), 
-do some stuff with data from the tables
-then disconnect.

My questions are: 
1- is it a bad idea connect and disconnect to the database everytime that this method runs? should I connect and disconnect in the main method and pass as an arguments the database handler??

2- this projects runs in my pc becouse I have MySQL process (I'm using Xampp) running and becouse I know database name and table name. If i want this project be able to run everywhere (without making the other people create a database with same name and table in their local mysql) should I create the db or tables from my project? is that possible?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How long will your program run? If it runs for 2 minutes and you do a connect every 10 seconds, that won't hurt at all. If no one else or only a small group of people is using the same database, you can do this for hours. Give us some more information. If it's a long-running application or a daemon or if you care about performance it could be an advantage to maintain a persistent connection (only one connect and disconnect). However, if there are others using the same database, you shouldn't hold a connection for such a long time. Better release it after every use (transaction or method call).
2. If you want the program to run anywhere, you could do this by making a web application out of it, e.g. using Tomcat. That is not too complicated for a simple database application. Another solution would be to use an embedded database like H2, HSQLDB or Apache Derby. You can ship these databases (and the data itself) with your application or project and whoever needs to run it doesn't have to install MySQL or additional software.

Comment: -It runs only a few minutes, with only one person connected to the database
-ok I will look into both those solution, didn't know embedded database even existed! Thanks!